# Create a Ruby feed of two un-related tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm creating an app that has two sets of content that's unrelated.

The first is Questions and Answers (Q&As) where a user can ask a question and the community can answer.

The second is an RSS like feed where an article is posted and links to a 3rd party site.

I'd like to create a 'Feed' so when the user logs in, they see the latest of the Q&As and the latest news all mixed together.  I've got it working now where they aren't mixed together.

So two questions, *how* do i combine the two data sets?  And what is the code to make it viewed given it's different content in each table.

Here is my code:
app>models>feed.rb

```
class Feed < ActiveRecord::Base
 validates :name, :url, :description, :source, presence: true
end
```

app>models>question.rb

```
class Feed < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy, foreign_key: "id"
end
```

app>controllers>feeds_controller.rb

```
def index
 @feeds = Feed.where("created_at >= ?", Date.today)
 @questions = Question.where("created_at >= ?", Date.today)  
end
```

app>views>feeds>index.html.erb

```
   <% @feeds.each do |feed| %>
    <h3><%= feed.name %></h3>
     <p><%= feed.source %></p>
      <p> <%= feed.created_at.strftime("%b %d, %Y") %> </p>            
      <%= link_to image_tag(feed.image.url(:medium)), feed.url %><br>
      <%= truncate(feed.description, length: 50) %><br>
   <% end %>    

   <% @questions.each do |question| %>
    <tr>
     <td><h1><%= link_to question.question , question_path(question) %></h1></td>
     <td><p>Posted by: <%= question.user.name %></p></td>
     <td> <p><%= question.created_at.strftime("%b %d, %Y") %> </p></td> 
     <td><p>Number of answers: <%= question.answers.count %> </p></td>         
    </tr>
   <% end %>
```

I don't think join works given they have different data. Any suggestions on how to combine feed and questions into one stream with the most recent at the top? (like a facebook feed).

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest this... which is doing array sorting, but I think you don't have a choice with two unrelated object types.

```
@combined = (@feeds.to_a + @questions.to_a).sort{|a,b| b.created_at <=> a.created_at}
```

Then in the view...

```
<% @combined.each do |combined| %>
  <%= render combined %>
<% end %>
```

The beauty of the `render` is that it will render a partial appropriate to the type of object.  If `combined` s a `Feed` object the partial used will be `feeds/_feed` but if it's a `Question` object it will use the partial `questions/_question`

Comment: Thank you for your very fast response.  I've tried the edit but i'm gettin the error
NoMethodError in FeedsController#index
undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
I checked and there are no blank entries in either the feeds or questions tables.... any additional suggestions?

Comment: Hi, yes, sorry, they're still relations, not arrays, so they need to be `to_a` (changed into arrays).  I will update the answer.

Comment: Thank you!  That fixed the error but now the page is rendering blank.. not showing any of the entries.  any additional ideas?

Comment: Did you create the partials? You need feeds/_feed.html.erb and questions/_question.html.erb

Comment: yes, i created the partials using the same code referenced above in the index (respectively moved into feeds and questions) and it's still coming up blank....Any additional tips?  Thanks for your help.  this has been a tough one to track down

Comment: Right so the _feed partial (and it starts with an underscore) has `feed.name` and `feed.source` and no loop, right? If so that's weird. Try putting in some constant text in the partial to see if it's at least rendering. E.g. `<h3>Hello</h3>`

Comment: I removed all other code and put <h3>Hello</h3> into  _feed.html.erb and _question.html.erb it's not showing up either. Which indicates that the partials aren't rendering

Comment: Ah, weird... and we're sure that `@combined.count` is non-zero?  if you `pry` into the app can you examine the `combined` object and see what happens when you try `combined.to_partial_path` and confirm it comes back with `feeds/feed` or `questions/question`? And _feed.html.erb is in the views/feeds directory, right?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working with a few small changes.  Rather than rendering the partial I did the following

```
<% @combined.each do |combined| %>
 <% if combined.is_a?(Feed) %>
  <h3><%= combined.name %></h3>
  <p><%= combined.source %></p
  ...
 <% else %>
<% end %>
```

Thank you for your help!